# Anonymous Type "Nullable object must have a value" Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am using an anonymous type to represent an object so that I can convert it into JSON format using the Json() method. Here is a sample of my code below.

The "MoviesList" variable is just a list of objects of type Objects.Movie.

```
        var result = new List<object>();
        foreach (Objects.Movie movie in MoviesList)
        {
            result.Add(new
            {
                CompletedTime = (movie.CompletedTime == null ? new Nullable<DateTime>() : movie.CompletedTime),
                Genre = movie.Genre,
                Title = movie.Title,
                Director = movie.Director
            });
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Before, I had the code written so that the CompletedTime property in the anonymous type is equal to the CompletedTime Property in the Movie object.

However, when I ran that and there were Movie objects in MoviesList where the CompletedTime Property was null (as the movie wasn't watched and therefore not finished yet), I got a **System.InvalidOperationException saying: Nullable object must have a value**.

So, I tried changing it to the code I have above, and I still get the same error.

I want a null value to be there if the movie has not been finished yet but I am getting this error. Is there any way to fix this or should I try a different approach?

**movie.CompletedTime is of type "DateTime?"**

**EDIT: Whenever I debug this code, the debugger goes into the foreach loop, and iterates. However, when it is on an iteration where an Objects.Movie object contains the property CompletedTime (movie.CompletedTime) where the value is null, it catches an error and returns me to the JsonResult type method that called the above code and returns the caught error**

StackTrace is below:

```
 at System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
   at WebService.Controllers.DataController.GenerateMovieList(DateTime date, String classID) in C:\WebService\Controllers\DataController.cs:line 212
   at WebService.Controllers.DataController.GetMovieList(String Date, String ClassID) in C:\WebService\Controllers\DataController.cs:line 133
```

Comment: What type is `movie.CompletedTime` ?

Comment: Are you sure the JSON writer you're using can handle nulls?

Comment: I understand `CompletedTime` is not nullable. What value is it supposed to have if `movie.CompletedTime` is null? Either make `CompletedTime` nullable or set it to the minimum value.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I am using the Json method from the Controller class under System.Web.MVC. It returns as type System.Web.MVC.JsonResult. I am actually not sure if it can handle nulls. Do you know if it can?

Comment: Did you try `CompletedTime = (DateTime?)movie.CompletedTime` ?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I actually want CompletedTime to be null whenever movie.CompletedTime is. Is this not possible?

Comment: 1. You need a value in your new DateTime or make it null (2nd option probably better). 2. Cast your actual object to a nullable type if you do have a value. CompletedTime = (movie.CompletedTime == null ? null : (DateTime?) movie.CompletedTime);

Comment: @ziddarth Just tried it and it gives me the same error. Isn't that just repetitive though because movie.CompletedTime is already of type 'DateTime?'?

Comment: `I actually want CompletedTime to be null whenever movie.CompletedTime is. Is this not possible?`  According to the error message you're getting, no.  It's specifically telling you that the nullable object must have a value (i.e. be not `null`).

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Why would the time of completion be an interval of time?  The *length* of a movie would be an interval, but the time of completion is not.

Comment: @Igor so do I have to cast  `var result = new List<object>();` to be a nullable type? How would I do that?

Comment: I just tested your code and it works without a problem for me. Can you narrow it down a bit more? I assume the exception occurs on the last line when you call method Json(result, ... ? Also can you try to remove all other properties in your anomyous object and see what happens then?

Comment: @Servy oh. so there's no way to bypass that? No typecasting or anything to allow nulls?

Comment: The type system is *already* allowing nulls.  The code you're passing the `null` value to is throwing an exception explicitly stating that it doesn't support `null`.  If you just weren't passing `null`, it obviously wouldn't be breaking in the first place.

Comment: @ziddarth Writing `?? null` is completely redundant.  You can just remove that entirely and it would have no effect on the code.

Comment: Where are you getting the movie list from and how? This usually happens when you try to use the .Value property of a DateTime if it's null.

Comment: @Servy you're right. That recommendation was useless.

Comment: @Servy  I am passing the code to the result variable, which is a list of the System.Object class. So that means that List<Object> doesn't support null? If not is there a better approach I can use to allow nulls to be passed into a JsonResult type method that converts objects to JSON? Or am I completely off haha

Comment: @user3587754 Of course it does; if it didn't, you couldn't construct the `List` in the first place, and you have already done it.  The method you're passing that `List` to doesn't support the `null` value.  The stack trace of the exception should make that quite clear.

Comment: Again, let me ask you: where do you get that movies list from exactly? Is it really just a List<Movie>?

Comment: @Servy in that case, the debugger would complete the iteration, but it doesn't. It doesn't even reach the return statement according to OPs latest edit.

Comment: @nXu the MoviesList is actually of type `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<Objects.Movie>`.

Comment: @user3587754 - if you post the stack trace found in the generated exception it would be much easier for everyone to see what was going on. Now all we can do is guess...

Comment: Try converting it to an Array or List with ToArray()  / ToList(), and check it out (with the debugger if necessary). I think there is something shady happening there.

Comment: @dbc The JSON Serializer I am using is the Json(obect data, JsonRequestBehaviour behaviour) method of type JsonResult. It can be found in the System.Web.Mvc.Controller Class. I am using the asp.net MVC Framework.

Comment: @Igor updated my question with stacktrace. Sorry about the wait

Comment: So it does look like you are doing a .Value on a nullable object that does not have a value. Try changing that one line to this : CompletedTime = movie.CompletedTime. It would also help to include the complete methods as you have them if this is not the answer.

Comment: @user3587754 - Can you let us know if that was the answer once you have a chance to test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your stack trace it does look like you are doing a .Value on a nullable object that does not have a value. Try changing that one line to this:

```
CompletedTime = movie.CompletedTime, // just pass in the nullable object as is
```

It would also help to include the complete methods as you have them if this is not the answer.